# Fixed menu won´t scroll when submenu opened in mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky

I´m using bootstrap3 and I´m trying to create a fixed menu for mobile devices. This menu can have submenu´s and submenu´s can have a lot of content in it. So when you watch the site on mobile phone´s (320x480 eg) and the menu is very long then you can´t scroll in the inner/submenu. In other words if your screen height is too short you can´t see all the menu items because the menu bar is sticked at the top of the screen.

I´ve read a lot of post from github and here + Bootstrap's page, but can´t seem to get it to work. I think that position fixed is the problem?!

I'll try to explain with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/j7d30hhb/) and here below
EDIT: You can view an example here -> [example](http://webdinge.webshopapp.com/en/) (resize browser and try to hit brands)

HTML

```
<div id="main-nav-container">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
      <nav id="main-nav">
        <div id="responsive-nav">
          <div id="responsive-nav-button">
            Menu <span id="responsive-nav-button-icon"></span>
          </div><!-- responsive-nav-button -->

        <ul class="clearfix responsive-nav">
          <li><a href="http://webdinge.webshopapp.com/nl/" class="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
          <li><span class="menu-button"></span><a title="Camera" href="http://www.webshop.com/nl/camera/">Camera</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a title="Canon" href="http://www.webshop.com/nl/camera/canon/">Canon</a></li>
                <li> like 40 li items more for example </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
etc...
```

JQUERY

```
 $(function() {
  var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#main-nav-container').offset().top;

  // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
  var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

    // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
      $('#main-nav-container').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
    } else {
      $('#main-nav-container').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
    }   
  };

  sticky_navigation();

  // and run it again every time you scroll
  $(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
  });
});
```

So how can I make the menu so that the  with the li items is scrollable so that on smaller screens the whole submenu can be viewed?

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to `#main-nav` or whatever is declaring the height of the menu?

Comment: Have a look at http://plugins.jquery.com/slimScroll/ It's a really lightweight plugin (< 5kB)

Comment: @Evan: Yes tried that, no luck :( Please check my edit to my question. That's a test site where you can see what I mean.

Comment: @singe31: Ok never heard of that! Is that something that would fix my problem if you see my example link to my test site?

Comment: So it looks like the actual toggle for brands actually links back to the page - but the menu toggle (+) actually trigger the dropdown - are you trying to have brands toggle this dropdown as well?

Comment: @Evan: No what I try is to make the dropdown (+) also scrollable or something. If you resize the browser to a very small size you'll will see that a few brands aren't visible because they won't scroll or because the main menu is fixed. I'm looking for an answer which will fix that.

Comment: @JaapVermoolen Yes with that plugin you can make your menu scrollable

Comment: Ah I see, try adding `.responsive-nav {
overflow-y: scroll;
position: fixed;
top: 58px;
height: 100%;
padding-bottom: 58px;
}`

Comment: @Evan: Ok I think I see what you're trying to do! I think I can do something with this. Thx man...

Comment: @Evan Ok this almost works! Thx for that. The only problem right now is that when the navbar/menu hasn't class fixed or is still at top of the screen the menu slides out on top of the screen. See my test site please